# Create classes which extend Tailwind css classes

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

I use Tailwind for my project and I would like to create classes which use tailwind existing classes. For example, my buttons currently look like this:

```
<button class="text-light-blue bg-white rounded-full border-solid border-2 border-light-blue py-1 px-4 box-border shadow hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white hover:border-blue-700">
       Button
</button>
```

As you can see I use a lot of classes and I would like to have instead something like this:

```
<button class="app-btn"> Button </button>
```

with

```
@import '/node_modules/tailwindcss/utilities.css';

.app-btn { 
   @extend .text-light-blue;
   @extend .bg-white;
   ...
}
```

but when I try to do this I have the following error:

```
SassError: ".app-btn" failed to @extend ".bg-white".
       The selector ".bg-white" was not found.
       Use "@extend .bg-white !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
        on line 4 of src/assets/styles/app-shared-style.scss
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried @apply? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply

Answer (score 14):

You can just do this:

```
.app-btn {
@apply text-white rounded-full py-1 px-4 shadow hover:bg-blue-700.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution:
You need to install `postcss-import` with `npm install postcss-import`, tweek the postcss.config.js with:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

and then you can create classes based on the lib classes with:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';

.app-btn {      
  @apply text-white;
  @apply rounded-full;
  @apply py-1;
  @apply px-4;
  @apply shadow;
  &:hover {
    @apply bg-blue-700;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a lot cleaner to use a single `@apply` and list each prop on its own line, ie:
```
@apply relative
max-w-3xl
mx-auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `laravel mix`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
```

You need to configure your `webpack.mix.js` in one of the following ways

1] you can either use `postCss` like this

```
mix.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
]);
```

2] or, you can use `sass` like this

```
mix.sass("resources/css/app.scss", "public/css").options({
    postCss: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ], });
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```css
    .input {
        @apply p-2 text-center mb-2 border rounded focus:outline outline-2 focus:outline-blue-500;
    }

    .file-input {
      @apply input border-none text-slate-500 leading-10 file:block md:file:inline-block file:w-full md:file:w-auto file:btn file:h-min file:border-none file:cursor-pointer file:mx-3;
    }
```

No CSS preprocessor needed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you must go to the file that included @component @utilities and @base then type:

```
@layer component{
   .class-name{
      @apply your classes
   }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).